# Inside an OnClickListener, how to fun a function multiple times with different arguments. The functions to run after the previous one has completed

Tags: function, kotlin, synchronization

hope someone can help. As the title says, inside a button onclick listener, I'm trying to run a Countdown Timer three times, each to run after the previous one is finished.

I then need to repeat this a number of times depending on the number of sets etc.
I've tried so many things, synchronizing the startTimer(x) function, ReentrantLock, boolean isComplete variables, 3 threads joined, GlobalScope.launch with join(), but each time the timers all start at the same time.
Can anyone suggest a solution?
Thanks!

```
override fun onClick(view: View?) {
//... other view click code...
R.id.btn_timer_startWorkout -> {
            val thrdA = Thread {
                // run prep time
                var prepTime = et_timer_prep.text.toString().toLong()
                timeInMilliseconds = prepTime.times(1000)
                startTimer(timeInMilliseconds, et_timer_prep)
            }
            val thrdB = Thread {
                // run work timer
                var workTime = et_timer_work.text.toString().toLong()
                timeInMilliseconds = workTime.times(1000)
                startTimer(timeInMilliseconds, et_timer_work)
            }
            val thrdC = Thread {
                // run work timer
                var restTime = et_timer_rest.text.toString().toLong()
                timeInMilliseconds = restTime.times(1000)
                startTimer(timeInMilliseconds, et_timer_rest)
            }
            thrdA.start()
            thrdA.join()
            thrdB.start()
            thrdB.join()
            thrdC.start()
            thrdC.join()
    }


private fun startTimer(prepTime: Long, editText: EditText) {

    countdown_timer = object : CountDownTimer(prepTime, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            timeInMilliseconds = millisUntilFinished
            updateUI(timeInMilliseconds, editText)
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            Toast.makeText(this@TimerActivity, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
    countdown_timer.start()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All your Threads are blocking on the main thread, so the UI cannot be updated until they all finish. This can also cause an Application Not Responding error (ANR).

To do this without coroutines, you need callbacks:

```
R.id.btn_timer_startWorkout -> {
    var prepTime = et_timer_prep.text.toString().toLong()
    timeInMilliseconds = prepTime.times(1000)
    startTimer(timeInMilliseconds, et_timer_prep) {
        var workTime = et_timer_work.text.toString().toLong()
        timeInMilliseconds = workTime.times(1000)
        startTimer(timeInMilliseconds, et_timer_work) {
            var restTime = et_timer_rest.text.toString().toLong()
            timeInMilliseconds = restTime.times(1000)
            startTimer(timeInMilliseconds, et_timer_rest) {}
        }
    }

}

private inline fun startTimer(prepTime: Long, editText: EditText, callback: () -> Unit) {

    countdown_timer = object : CountDownTimer(prepTime, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            timeInMilliseconds = millisUntilFinished
            updateUI(timeInMilliseconds, editText)
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            Toast.makeText(this@TimerActivity, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            callback()
        }
    }
    countdown_timer.start()
}
```

Coroutines can save you from the ugly nested callbacks. You should launch them from `lifecycleScope`, not GlobalScope, so they can work with your UI elements:

```
R.id.btn_timer_startWorkout -> {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        var prepTime = et_timer_prep.text.toString().toLong()
        timeInMilliseconds = prepTime.times(1000)
        startTimer(timeInMilliseconds, et_timer_prep)

        var workTime = et_timer_work.text.toString().toLong()
        timeInMilliseconds = workTime.times(1000)
        startTimer(timeInMilliseconds, et_timer_work)

        var restTime = et_timer_rest.text.toString().toLong()
        timeInMilliseconds = restTime.times(1000)
        startTimer(timeInMilliseconds, et_timer_rest) {}
    }
}

private suspend fun startTimer(prepTime: Long, editText: EditText) {
    var elapsed = 0L
    while (elapsed < prepTime) {
        val delay = min(1000L, prepTime - elapsed)
        delay(delay)
        elapsed += delay
        timeInMilliseconds = prepTime - elapsed
        updateUI(timeInMilliseconds, editText)
    }
    Toast.makeText(this@TimerActivity, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Comment: Hi, the first solution worked for me but then I tried to include it in a nested loop to repeat and it went dead again. Guess I'll have to read around callbacks before I can progress this. But thank you for your excellent response.

Comment: @AJones To loop it using callbacks, you would have to store the outermost callback in a local variable, and reference it in the inner-most callback. This is much easier using the coroutines solution, because you can freely put the code in a loop.